# Random() заполнение не с нуля java

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Собственно кто знает как это сделать? Думалось сделать Random(20) * 20; но это бешеное число, так что мне нужен другой выход.

Comment: Не понятно ничего.. что значит не с нуля и почему rnd(20) * 20 - бешенное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно, что конкретно вам надо, но видимо как всегда одно и то же. И тут, и в гугле миллион один ответ по теме, и всё равно его упорно задают

```
Random rnd = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
int number = rnd.nextInt(to - from) + from;
```

позволяет получать числа в интервале [from; to)

Comment: Почему не используете дефолтный конструктор Random? Ведь он делает ровно тоже самое:  public Random() { this(System.currentTimeMillis()); }

Comment: Это привычка со старых времён, когда это было не так.

Comment: для справки, иногда удобнее использовать Math.rand();

Comment: Чес слово не нашел я в интернетах такого примера, спасибо огромное!

Comment: от себя добавлю что иногда бывают ситуации (напр. в целях безопасности), когда вам надо одновременно "суперпупермегабольшое" число и число которое влезает в определенный диапазон. тогда генерируют большое случайное число, а маленькое будет остатком большого по модулю

p.s. хотя врядли это то что интересует автора :)